# Loading zepto modules with requirejs

Tags: javascript, requirejs, zepto

I'm new to RequireJS and I'm trying to understand the logic behind its use...

I have the following script between html script tag

```
requirejs.config(
    {shim: {
        'zepto': ['//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/zepto/1.1.4/zepto.min.js'],
        'js/zepto.addon.min' : 'zepto',
        'js/zepto.swipeslide' : ['zepto', 'js/zepto.addon.min']
    }}
    );

define(['//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/zepto/1.1.4/zepto.min.js','js/zepto.addon.min','js/zepto.swipeslide'],function(){
    console.log('this', this, 'arguments', arguments);
});`
```

I'm simply trying to load the necessary zepto files before the plugin. However I'm getting a

> Uncaught Error: Mismatched anonymous define() module: function (){
>     console.log('this', this, 'arguments', arguments); }

I'm looking up the error under the requirejs docs but it does not make it clear what and why this is happening.

Can you guys break it down for me in layman's terms what's going on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That setup doesn't make much sense. You should define your paths, define your shims, and then require those modules by name.

```
requirejs.config({
    // setup global dependencies
    shim: {
        'addon' : 'zepto',
        'swipeslide' : ['zepto', 'addon']
    },
    // define module paths
    paths: {
        'zepto': '//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/zepto/1.1.4/zepto.min',
        'addon': 'js/zepto.addon.min',
        'swipeslide': 'js/zepto.swipeslide'
    }
});

define(['zepto', 'addon', 'swipeslide'], function($) {
    console.log('this', this, 'arguments', arguments);
});
```

Comment: So you are saying the "shims" are like "aliases" that link your dependencies for scripts when you define them?

Comment: Maybe? I don't think so. `paths` are aliases of the form `module:path`. `shims` are dependency definitions of the form `module:[dependencies]`. Shims are for packages which need to be required in a specific order relative to other dependencies.

Comment: @Mathletics....I tried your code but for some reason the arguments in the function are all returning "undefined"... doesn't requirejs scope the scripts variables?

Comment: what do you mean? `arguments` is coming back `[undefined, undefined, undefined]`? Do those paths map to things that actually exist?